# Robots.txt deny all except for one domain

Tags: robots.txt

Is there a way to deny all robots except for one domain? I want search engines to not crawl unless it is a certain domain.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your comments to the other answer correctly, you have a wildcard subdomain so that foo.example.com and bar.example.com and fooby.example.com all end up going to the same place. There is only one physical path that serves all of those domains.

If that's the case, then you can't do this with a single robots.txt file. The rules in robots.txt are all based on stuff that comes *after* the domain name.

I would suggest that you create a robots.txt file in that directory that contains:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

That will block all bots from crawling anything.

Now, assuming that you want to allow crawling only if it's an access to foo.example.com, I would create a rewrite rule so that attempts to access foo.example.com/robots.txt instead get their data from foo.example.com/robots_foo.txt. And that file would contain:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Which allows access to everything. Of course, you could add whatever disallow rules you want to this.

If you can't create rewrite rules, then you'll have to go with [Sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/). The disadvantage, of course, is that not all crawlers understand Sitemaps. Some will still want to crawl the old way.

Answer (score -1):

User-agent: *

Disallow: /

User-agent: `The robot you want to allow`

Allow: /

Comment: My app can be installed on a wildcard subdomain I am trying to block all robots except for one subdomain

Comment: So you only want the robots to access one of your subdomains?

Comment: Yes, and disallow for everything else

Comment: You will need to place a seperate robots.txt file in the root directory of each subdomain. The subdomain you wish to give access would contain the contents I listed above. You would need to change it slightly to allow all robots to access that particular subdomain, it that's more of what you want. All of the others would disallow with the wildcard.